# How to add text in current position of the pointer in a textarea under tinyMCE?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using this html code:

```
<textarea id="furmul" style="height: 300px;"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="ok">OK</button>
```

I use these lines to add text to the current positon of the pointer for a simple textarea:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
insertAtCaret: function(myValue){
  return this.each(function(i) {
    if (document.selection) {
      //For browsers like Internet Explorer
      this.focus();
      sel = document.selection.createRange();
      sel.text = myValue;
      this.focus();
    }
    else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
      //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
      var startPos = this.selectionStart;
      var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
      var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+myValue+this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
      this.focus();
      this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
      this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
      this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    } else {
      this.value += myValue;
      this.focus();
    }
  })
}
});
```

But as you know to add a value to a tinyMCE we should use

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(myValue)
```

And for getting a tinyMCE content we use:

```
tinyMCE.get(id).getContent()
```

No the question is this that where in `insertAtCaret` function should I replace the above code to add `myValue` to the current position of the pointer in tinyMCE?

This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gHN8G/12/) may help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tinymce API

```
tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').execCommand('insertHTML', false, my_value);
```

Have a look at your altered fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gHN8G/13/

Comment: Thank you.It was greate my friend.

Comment: glad to have been able to help